# Не могу добавить в БД значения из textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf

У меня есть 2 TextBox: reg_log и reg_pas

Также есть база данных [dbo].[users] в которых содержатся 2 столбца

Не могу понять как мне сделать правильно запрос, чтобы текст из этих элементов добавился в БД

Могу добавить конкретные значения, которые впишу в код, например:

```
....Select("INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] VALUES ('test','test')");
```

В БД появится test | test

Как мне вместо test | test получить значения из textbox?

Comment: У `TextBox` должно быть какое-то свойство, из которого можно получить его значение. Обычно такие свойства могут называться `.Value`, либо `.Text`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @aepot - нельзя использовать AddWithValue. [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov _The overload of `Add` that takes a string and an object **was deprecated** because of possible ambiguity with the `SqlParameterCollection.Add` overload that takes a `String` and a `SqlDbType` enumeration value where passing an integer with the string could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the corresponding `SqlDbType` value._

Comment: @aepot - есть несколько версий метода `Add`. Среди них устаревшая, которая не принимает `SqlDbType`, её не стоит применять. Применять нужно другие, которые принимают этот тип.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov будет неплохо, если вы найдете или запостите ответ, который является правильным. Потому что я не нашел, а нашел только неправильные.

Comment: Как вы работаете с БД, с помощью чего? Используете сырой ADO.NET? Непонятна конструкция `...Select("INSERT ...")` - что означает `select`?

Answer (score 0):

https://metanit.com/sharp/adonetcore/2.8.php - здесь подробно и понятно описана возможность параметризации запроса.

Суть в том, что в то место в запросе, де необходимо вставить значение, нужно прописать имя параметра, который за это отвечает.